# Convergence in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Please i need help for this for $w\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, we define $w_R(x)=h_{R}(x)w(x)$

where $h\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N,[0,1]), h(x)=1,~ x\in B_1(0)$ and $h(x)=0,~ x\in B^c_2(0)$ and $R>0$ , $h_{R}(x)=h(\frac{x}{R})$

How to show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}(|\nabla w_{R_n}|^p+|w_{R_n}|^p)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}(|\nabla w|^p+|w|^p)dx$$

with $(R_n)$ is a real sequence such that $R_{n}\to \infty$ when $n\to\infty$.

I must use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, but how we obtain how we obtain the simple convergence ?

Thank you

Comment: @Wraith1995 There is no smooth function identically $1$ on $B_{1}(0)$ and identically zero on $\mathbb{R}^{N} \setminus B_{2}(0)$.

Comment: Oh, yeah... and it also I just realized it does not really affect the method of proof that I would suggest. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $h_{R}(x) = 1$ if $|x| \leq R$ by definition of $h$ and $h_{R}$.  Thus, $\lim_{n \to \infty} h_{R_{n}}(x) = 1$ everywhere.  From this, we see that $w_{R_{n}}(x) \to w(x)$ and $\nabla w_{R_{n}}(x) \to \nabla w(x)$ pointwise on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$.  Then apply the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, as you suggested.

Comment: What bout if $|x|\geq R$ ? and please what is the dominated function ?

Comment: Please explain me why $h_{R_n}(x)=1$

Comment: Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$.  Since $R_{n} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, it follows that there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x| \leq R_{n}$ for all $n \geq N$.  Thus, $\left|\frac{x}{R_{n}}\right| \leq 1$, which implies $h_{R_{n}}(x) = h \left(\frac{x}{R_{n}}\right) = 1$ by choice of $h$.  Since this is true for all $n \geq N$, it follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} h_{R_{n}}(x) = 1$.

Comment: i don't understand the first line please

Comment: please what is the dominated function to use the L.D.C theorem ?